# preg_match issue in reading pipeline

Tags: php, preg-match

```
<?php     
$value='A';
    if(preg_match("/|/",$value)){
        echo 'This is no good!';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Works';
    }
?>
```

If you execute the above code you can see that the `preg_match()` is not working while I don't have `|` or pipeline in the variable.

**Why preg_match is not working for single character or pipeline character?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical pipe character (`|`) has a special meaning when used inside a regular expression. It is used for specifying alternatives in a regular expression. You need to properly escape it if you want to match the literal `|` character:

```
if(preg_match("/\|/",$value)){
    # code ...
}
```

Comment: @BannedfromSO: They can be used as delimiters, if that's what you're asking. However, `|` serve a different purpose. Say, if you wanted to match `a` or `b`, then you'd write: `/a|b/`. [See demo](https://eval.in/75547).